Rails Client-side form checkbox validation: at least one value must be chosen
How do I check from the client-side if there is at least one checkbox being ticked here?
= form_with model: @form, url: generate_matches_tournament_path(@tournament), method: :post, local: true do |f|
  .field.justify-center.mb-4.mt-3.w-full.form-group
    = f.label :available_weekdays, 'Available Weekdays', class: "block text-sm font-bold mb-2"
    .checkbox_container.rounded-xl.p-4
      - weekdays = [['Monday', 'Mon'], ['Tuesday', 'Tue'], ['Wednesday', 'Wed'], ['Thursday', 'Thu'], ['Friday', 'Fri'], ['Saturday', 'Sat'], ['Sunday', 'Sun']]
      = f.collection_check_boxes :available_weekdays, weekdays, :second, :first do |b|
        .checkbox_item
          = b.check_box(class: 'checkbox')
          = b.label(class: 'ml-2') { b.text }

    - if @form.errors[:available_weekdays].any?
      .text-red-500.text-xs.mt-1
        = @form.errors[:available_weekdays].first


I am using Rails 7, Vite.
For context, I already have a server-side check and display the errors, but that is after the request is sent, which I kind of want to avoid in the first place.
I tried simply add required: true in the
= f.collection_check_boxes :available_weekdays, weekdays, :second, :first, required: true do |b|
but to no one's surprise, this did not work.
I am aware that I can use javascript to make this work, but I'd prefer a built-in or a more Rails way to do this, so that I can make use of this:
validation tooltip

Could you try to add required: true for each checkbox_item instead of whole collection_check_boxes => b.check_box(class: 'checkbox', required: true)  # Add 'required: true'
